# Xamarin forms operating camera gives empty exception

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm working on a mobile Android app using Xamarin Forms and Visual Studio.

I'm using the CrossMedia Plugin to be able to take or select photo's in my mobile app. At first I had problems with the initialize and that issue appeared to be caused by the wrong Android SDK I was targeting. After I updated the SDK and updated all the packages I was able to get the 'select a photo' option working, but using the camera still doesn't work, and I can't figure out what is causing this.

I've got the following method;

```
private async void TakeAPhoto(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("ERROR", "Error initializing camera!", "Ok");
    }

    var cameraStatus = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Camera);
    var storageStatus = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Storage);

    if (cameraStatus != PermissionStatus.Granted || storageStatus != PermissionStatus.Granted)
    {
        var results = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(new[] { Permission.Camera, Permission.Storage });
        cameraStatus = results[Permission.Camera];
        storageStatus = results[Permission.Storage];
    }

    if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("No camera", "No camera available", "Ok");
        return;
    }

    if (cameraStatus == PermissionStatus.Granted && storageStatus == PermissionStatus.Granted)
    {
        MediaFile file;
        try
        {
            //Exception occurs in this code.
            file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
            {
                //Specify Store to Album OR Directory, not both
                Directory = "App_Images",
                Name = "Test.jpg"

            });
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            //I've got a break point here which is being hit, but the exception is (null)
            throw;
        }

        if (file == null)
            return;

        //TODO: Store image to azure.
    }
    else
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Permissions Denied", "Unable to take photos.", "OK");
        //On iOS you may want to send your user to the settings screen.
        //CrossPermissions.Current.OpenAppSettings();
    }
}
```

However, when I'm running the code I'm getting an empty exception, it just says '(null)';

[image]

The debug window of Visual Studio gives me a lot of information, but the only real exception I see here is an 'InvocationException';

```
InspectorDebugSession(0): HandleTargetEvent: TargetHitBreakpoint
InspectorDebugSession(0): StateChange: EntryPointBreakpointRegistered -> EntryPointBreakpointHit
InspectorDebugSession(0): AgentBridge.InjectAssembly: /mnt/shell/emulated/0/Android/data/MyFirstAppPackage.MyFirstAppPackage/files/.__override__/inspector-temp/Xamarin.Interactive.dll
InspectorDebugSession(0): AgentBridge.InjectAssembly: Mono.Debugger.Soft.InvocationException: Exception of type 'Mono.Debugger.Soft.InvocationException' was thrown.
   at Mono.Debugger.Soft.InvocationsAPI.EndInvokeMethodInternalWithResultImpl(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Xamarin.Interactive.IdeSupport.AgentBridge.InjectAssembly(String agentAssemblyPath) in C:\d\lanes\4699\fec6f88f\source\xamarinvs\External\inspector-ide-integration\Xamarin.Interactive.IdeSupport\AgentBridge.cs:line 55
   at Xamarin.Interactive.IdeSupport.InspectorDebuggerSession.<HandleTargetEvent>b__26_0(Object <p0>) in C:\d\lanes\4699\fec6f88f\source\xamarinvs\External\inspector-ide-integration\Xamarin.Interactive.IdeSupport\InspectorDebuggerSession.cs:line 242
InspectorDebugSession(0): StateChange: EntryPointBreakpointHit -> Error
InspectorDebugSession(0): Disposed
```

I've been busy for quite some time to try and figure this out, but I'm completely stuck on this at the moment. I've also tried remote debugging by attaching a Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini to my computer, but it gives me the same error. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: maybe a debugging artefact. I already saw the combination of mono, emulator/device and visual studio do stuff more weird than this. try a `Debug.Write(exception.ToString());` instead of the `throw` and see if that outputs anything useful.

Comment: I ran your function with no problems on Android emulator, it worked. It is known problem with variables with the same name in one function. You have 2 "exception" variables. Chnage one to "ex1" and you will be able to see an exception.

Comment: As Yuri said, there two kinds of exception: `System.Exception` and `Java.Lang.Exception`. I don't know what type `Exception` you are using, but it seems that the exception you catch doesn't belong to the `Exception` you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this issue resolved by simply selecting the proper Android version to compile on. The plugin documentation says the compile version of android needs to be set to Android 6.0, I had it set to 7.0 because I thought this was possible. But it's not.

Also the target android version was set to a higher version. Setting these both to Android 6.0 fixed the issue.

For more information see the documentation [here](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin).